# Is there a Django manage.py command for running Celery worker?

Tags: django, django-celery

I created a short Python script to launch the Celery worker for the current Django via:

```py
from celery.bin import worker

worker.worker(app=my_app).run()
```

This works great and utilizes all the correct settings so there's no need to specify all the myriad command-line arguments of `celery` (and I can launch it via [debugpy](https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy/) and remote debug it from a container in VS Code).

My question is whether there is a `manage.py` command I can run to achieve the same thing?

(NOTE: Using Celery 4.3 and Django 2.2)

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-management-commands/? Just put your script in the `handle` method.

Answer (score 2):

Applications can register their own actions with `manage.py`. For example, you might want to add a `manage.py` action for a Django app that you’re distributing.

To do this, add a management/commands directory to the application. Django will register a `manage.py` command for each Python module in that directory whose name doesn’t begin with an underscore. For example:

```
YOUR_APP/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    management/
        __init__.py
        commands/
            __init__.py
            runcelery.py
    tests.py
    views.py
```

In this example, the **runcelery** command will be made available to any project that includes the **YOUR_APP** application in INSTALLED_APPS.

The `runcelery.py` module has only one requirement – it must define a class Command that extends BaseCommand or one of its subclasses.

To implement the command, edit `YOUR_APP/management/commands/runcelery.py` to look like this:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from celery.bin import worker

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Run celery worker'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        worker.worker(app=my_app).run()
```

you can now run it from **manage.py** like this: `python manage.py runcelery`

check this [article](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-management-commands/) for more information.